# Why I cannot register '.as_view()' in the Django router (using djangorestframework-simplejwt)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have been trying to add djangorestframework-simplejwt to my webapp and whenever I use the router to add the views (see the 2 commented routers in the code below) - I get an error (see traceback).

When adding the urls [as the documentation says](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#requirements) - under the `urlpatterns` variable - it works without any errors. I would like to know why this isn't working through the `router.register(..)` and for the sake of good order (and my OCD), is it possible to move it out of the urlpatterns variable to the router.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

app_name = 'myapi'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'posts', views.PostViewSet)
router.register(r'user', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'likes', views.LikesViewSet)
# router.register(r'token',TokenObtainPairView.as_view())
# router.register(r'token/refresh',jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view())

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)), 
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

traceback:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/test/Projects/ppproject/src/ufb/urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    path('api/', include('myapi.urls', namespace='myapi')),
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/test/Projects/ppproject/src/myapi/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    router.register(r'token',TokenObtainPairView.as_view())
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 54, in register
    basename = self.get_default_basename(viewset)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/ppproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 137, in get_default_basename
    assert queryset is not None, '`basename` argument not specified, and could ' \
AssertionError: `basename` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.
```

Comment: It makes no sense to pass a view to a router, since the idea of a router is to construct *multiple* paths: one for the detail, one for the list, etc. These are all different views that are combined in a viewset. A router does *not* construct paths for a single view.

Comment: FWIW, the only sensible tag for this question is `django-rest-framework`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routers work with `ViewSets` and not with API Views, so you can't add them at that level.

In Django land, every url maps to a view *function*, and it is the `Router`'s job to convert that ViewSet to a list of functions that django's `path` knows how to handle, by routing `GET` to the `list()` function, etc.  So `router.urls` is a list of django `path` instances.

You can [even do it manually](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#binding-viewsets-to-urls-explicitly) if you really like to confuse others!

```
snippet_list = SnippetViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})

path('snippets/', snippet_list, name='snippet-list'),
```

The way you are adding them now is correct.  [`as_view`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L122) is a DRF function which converts an `APIView` or related class **into** a view function for django's `path` to work with.

I have a [`route()` helper](https://gist.github.com/awbacker/4b78b91a423177bcc1db4ec3e12e25fa) which you might find helpful. It unifies routing for views, '.urls', viewsets, and replaces `path()`.  I found this was one of my biggest frustrations over the years.

```
urlpatterns = [
    route('students/', 'student.urls'),
    route('users/', UserViewSet, name='user'),
    route('register/', RegisterView, name='register'),
    ...
```